# Importing csv file with commas in it Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, google-sheets, export-to-csv

I am importing a csv file  and a column in this csv file can have commas in it. So when I import it increases the columns .

```
3,Stage3,"Desc Stage,test,test2",55.98,98.76
```

This is the row and I want my columns to be :

```
3,
Stage3,
"Desc Stage,test,test2",
55.98,
98.76
```

Comment: What kind of madman chooses to use a .csv format with comma delimited data?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    public static string[] splitCSV(string CSVLineWithQuotedTextWithCommas)
    {
        Regex regExToSeperate = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        string curr = null;
        foreach (Match match in regExToSeperate.Matches(CSVLineWithQuotedTextWithCommas))
        {
            curr = match.Value;
            if (0 == curr.Length)
            {
                result.Add("");
            }

            result.Add(curr.TrimStart(','));
        }
        return result.ToArray<string>();
    }
```